# Conversion of Binary fractions to Decimal in C# GUI

Tags: c#

How do you convert binary fractions to decimal in c#? eg: 1101.101 is supposed to be 13.625, I get 1.25 which is way off. I seem to get errors when I put a fractional binary number, no problems on whole Binary numbers. I can show my code if needed.

Code:

```
double tempans = 0;
        double answer = 0;
        string finAns;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] temp = new string[5];
            string strHldr = textBox1.Text;
            bool isFractional = strHldr.Contains('.');
            double val1 = 0;
            double val2 = 0;

            if (!isFractional)
                finAns = ComputePart(strHldr);
            else
            {
                string wholeP = WholePart(strHldr);
                string deciP = DecimalPart(strHldr);
                val1 = double.Parse(ComputePart(wholeP));
                val2 = double.Parse(ComputeDeci(deciP));
                finAns = (val2 +  val2).ToString();
            }
            textBox1.Text = finAns;
        }
        private string ComputePart(string strHldr)
        {
            double length1 = strHldr.Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < strHldr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (strHldr[i] == '1')
                {
                    tempans = Math.Pow(2, length1);
                    answer += tempans;
                }
                length1 -= 1;
            }
            length1 = 0;
            return answer.ToString();
        }
        private string ComputeDeci(string number)
        {
            double ans = 0;
            double counter = 1;
            double finalAns = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
           { 
                ans = counter * 0.5;
                counter = ans;
                if (number[i] == '1')
                {
                    finalAns += counter;
                }
            }
            return finalAns.ToString();
        }
        private string DecimalPart(string number)
        {
            int numCut = number.IndexOf('.');
            return number.Substring(numCut + 1);
        }
        private string WholePart(string number)
        {
            return ((int)Math.Floor(double.Parse(number))).ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your codes. Needed.

Comment: My bad. It was a typo. Posting codes, brb.

Comment: My comment about it being 13.625 was non-sense. Sorry, 11.625 is the answer you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo in your code:

```
finAns = (val2 +  val2).ToString();
```

should be

```
finAns = (val1 +  val2).ToString();
```

Note that val2 was added to val2 rather than val1 being added to val2.

Comment: That explains the 1.25

Comment: Wow man, i checked it more than 2x and didn't notice I got my error from this. Thanks. Need to focus more on reading my own codes. lol

Comment: No problem. Apologies for suggesting it should be 13.625 and not 11.625, I had a brain fart.

Comment: No, it was nice of you. :)